# Set a reference of a new Bitmap from within an AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

This may be more of a Java question than an Android question, but I'm having trouble retrieving a Bitmap created within an AsyncTask to store in another class (an Activity) so that I can recycle it when I'm done using it.

The AsyncTask creates the Bitmap in doInBackground() and sets it as the bitmap for an ImageView in onPostExecute(), the ImageView being passed in through the constructor. But after completion I want the Bitmap to be accessible in the Activity. The Activity has an ArrayList of ImageViews and another of Bitmaps, but since the AsyncTask creates a new Bitmap, I can't find an easy way to get this new object in the ArrayList of Bitmaps in the Activity. Currently I have it working by passing in the ArrayList along with an index into the list to the AsyncTask constructor, and doInBackground just sets that entry in the array to the newly created bitmap.

I don't like this solution though, because I want to be able to use this AsyncTask for different things, perhaps where the Activity doesn't have an ArrayList of Bitmaps. And I can't simply give the AsyncTask constructor a Bitmap because Java passes the reference by value, and setting it to a new Bitmap object wouldn't allow access for the caller.

How can I do this more elegantly?

Here is the relevant code. Lines not pertaining to this question have been omitted for clarity.

```java
public class LoadCachedImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private Context context;
    private ImageView image;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps;
    int index;

    public LoadCachedImageTask(Context context, ImageView image, ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps, int index) {
        this.context = context;
        this.image = image;
        this.bitmaps = bitmaps;
        this.index = index;
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String url = urls[0];
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        // Create the bitmap
        File imageFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "test");
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());

        // Set the bitmap to the bitmap list
        bitmaps.set(index, bitmap);

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void arg) {
        // Display the image
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmaps.get(index));
    }

    protected void onCancelled() {
        if (bitmaps.get(index) != null) {
            bitmaps.get(index).recycle();
            bitmaps.set(index, null);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's a sample Activity that uses it.

```java
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<ImageView> images;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        images = new ArrayList<ImageView>();
        bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        int numImages = 15;

        // Create the images and bitmaps
        for (int i = 0; i < numImages; i++) {
            images.add(new ImageView(this));
            bitmaps.add(null);
        }

        // Load the bitmaps
        for (int i = 0; i < numImages; i++) {
            new LoadCachedImageTask(this, images.get(i), bitmaps, i).execute("http://random.image.url");
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested the above code, so it might not work, but I think it gets the point across.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you're trying to load a large number of bitmaps into a large number of `ImageViews` asynchronously.  I would think this can be done with a single `AsyncTask` class that you use multiple times for each `ImageView`.

You're `AsyncTask` should be something like this:

```
  public class LoadCachedImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> mImgView;

    public LoadCachedImageTask(ImageView image) {
      mImageView = new WeakReference<ImageView>(image);
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
      if(urls == null || urls.length < 1) 
        return;

      // Create the bitmap
      final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url);

      return bitmap;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bmp) {
        // Display the image
      if(bmp != null) {
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) mImgView.get();
        if(imageView != null) // needed in case the weakreference is removed
          imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}
```

Then to fill your array of ImageViews with something like this:

```
for(ImageView imgView : images) {
   (new LoadCachedImageTask<String, Void, Bitmap>)(imgView).execute(getBitmapUrl());
}
```

The for-loop will iterate through each `ImageView` reference and pass it to a brand new `AsyncTask` reference.  It will then execute the AsyncTask with the given url to whatever bitmap you need.  The asynctask will hold on to a reference of the ImageView so long as the ImageView exists.  If, for some reason, your ImageView got destroyed, the bitmap will still load then immediately get thrown away.

Comment: I see you're recycling the Bitmap directly after setting it to the ImageView. Won't this cause problems when trying to draw that ImageView?

Comment: I think the bitmap is copied in the ImageView because it has it's own scaling mechanisms built in so the recycling wouldn't affect it. Now that you mention it, though.  None of my personal code does this.  It should work though, but please tell me if it doesn't and I'll edit.

Comment: I've run some tests and found that recycling a Bitmap currently used in an ImageView results in `java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap`. This is actually the reason I need to hold on to the bitmap references - so that I can recycle them when they're done being used to try and save memory.

Comment: In that case, I'll edit it.  The rest should still work though.